# Generating a string with elements from an array based on pattern matching

Tags: ruby, arrays, pattern-matching

I have an array like this:

```
inList = ["edge_rabbit", "nsp_edge_rabbit", "services", "syslog", "master_rabbit", "mongod", ...]
```

How can I take the elements that end with `_rabbit` or elements with the format `mongo[cds]`, and  generate a comma separated string like the following?

```
"edge_rabbit, nsp_edge_rabbit, master_rabbit"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the one you are looking for using [**`String#end_with?`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-end_with-3F) and [**`Array#select`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-select)?

```
inList = ["edge_rabbit", "nsp_edge_rabbit", "services", "syslog", "master_rabbit", "mongod"]
inList.select{|e| e.end_with?('_rabbit')}.join(", ")
# => "edge_rabbit, nsp_edge_rabbit, master_rabbit"
```

or

```
inList = ["edge_rabbit", "nsp_edge_rabbit", "services", "syslog", "master_rabbit", "mongod"]
inList.grep(/_rabbit$/).join(", ")
# => "edge_rabbit, nsp_edge_rabbit, master_rabbit"


inList = ["edge_rabbit","_rabbit_ut", "nsp_edge_rabbit", "services", "syslog", "master_rabbit", "mongod","mongos","mongoy"]
inList.grep(/_rabbit$|^mongo[cds]/).join(", ")
# => "edge_rabbit, nsp_edge_rabbit, master_rabbit, mongod, mongos"
```

Comment: I knew this gonna be so simple that I'm not even thinking about it. Thanks a lot for the prompt answer. Cheers!!

Comment: On a separate note, is it possible to use pattern-matching/regex with `include`, like `inList.include? ()`? e.g. to check if any of the array elements ends with `_rabbit`. Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers not with [`#include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) But with yes `#grep` you can do.  See my update.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use some small patterns:

```
in_list = ["edge_rabbit", "nsp_edge_rabbit", "services", "syslog", "master_rabbit", "mongod"]

in_list.select{ |s| s[/(?:^mongo)|(?:_rabbit$)/] }.join(', ') # => "edge_rabbit, nsp_edge_rabbit, master_rabbit, mongod"
```

Or:

```
in_list.grep(/(?:^mongo)|(?:_rabbit$)/).join(', ') # => "edge_rabbit, nsp_edge_rabbit, master_rabbit, mongod"
```

If it's possible to have variations on `mongo` with other trailing characters besides `c`, `d` or `s`, then use:

```
in_list.grep(/(?:^mongo[cds])|(?:_rabbit$)/).join(', ') # => "edge_rabbit, nsp_edge_rabbit, master_rabbit, mongod"
```

Comment: @the Tin Man: Very useful for a Ruby newbie; thanks for heads up! Cheers!!